# Feature selection

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have several data points for which, whenever I activate the `select feature` button and complete the marking out of the points I need, the mark outs vanish. In other words, the points are not selected even though I enclose them in any of the `Select Features by` tools.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS SE! Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish after selecting the points?

Comment: Can you select these features one-by-one? Have you made sure the features are on the vetor-layer you have marked?

Comment: Thanks for the contributions!

Comment: I have found the error; after converting the initial layer into a shapefile before proceeding with the selection, it's now working.

Comment: @Jojo could you please answer your own question and afterwards select your answer as the solution? So this question is marked as solved.